# How to report a user who edits questions and answers that are not required?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits

How to report user who are editing question and answer unrelated? I found many users that edit answers with too minor and invalidating edits. I want to know how can I report these users.

Answer (score 10):

Flag one of the editor's posts for moderation attention *once*, and *clearly* explain what's going on. The moderators will take it from there.

Comment: I just did that today. Thought it would be best to let a moderator know about what a user is doing. Just adding few extra spaces and done. That's an edit for me to review. :-(

Comment: But how to Knw SO take action for it flag..?